# Rails and paperclip, delete the record but don't delete the attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, callback, paperclip

I'm using rails and paperclip to save images, the usual way.

When a record with an attachment is destroyed, the attachment also gets deleted from the file system.

99% of the time this is the correct action, however there is a case where I need the attachment to remain in the system even though the db record is deleted.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this.

I've tried setting the attachment fields to nil via an update_attribute before destroying the record, but the update_attribute also delete the file.

One way would be to ignore all the callbacks, however some of the other call backs are needed and this seems a little too much. Anyone know any better ways...

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to take a look at how `Attachment#assign` (called when you do `object.attachment = new_attachment`) is implemented in paperclip. 
Basically, it makes a bit of setup, then calls `Attachment#clear`, then it saves the new file.

Attachment#clear puts the old file in a deletion queue that is processed when you call save again, what you want is simply to avoid the call to clear, which you could do by either writing a new assign method which skips that line or by monkey patching `#clear` so that it becomes a no-op. In theory you could just monkey patch it on the instances where you want this to happen, but it seems to me you may want to do it for the whole project.

Or you can clear the instance variable holding the processing queue. That variable does not have an accessor, but it should be trivial to do an `instance_variable_get`

Answer (score 3):

The gem allows you to do a soft delete:

(from [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file-preservation-for-soft-delete))

### File Preservation for Soft-Delete

An option is available to preserve attachments in order to play nicely with soft-deleted models. (acts_as_paranoid, paranoia, etc.)

```
has_attached_file :some_attachment, {
    preserve_files: true,
}
```

This will prevent some_attachment from being wiped out when the model gets destroyed, so it will still exist when the object is restored later.

Comment: True should not be a string.

Comment: fixed! Thanks @yekta

Answer (score 1):

Nil-ling the database fields that paperclip generates (file_name, content_type, file_size) would not keep the file. The destroy method will still point it through the index.

Try changing the id to some random number (e.g. 999898) before you destroy the record. If it throws exception, also nil the fields. That way the record will no longer points at the file and will remain as the record gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is what is going on? You are trying to implement undo so someone can delete and then undelete?

I would argue that your solution should be dealing with a "clear" flag and then deleting in a batch job nightly if the clear flag is true. Would not impact performance as long as all gets are for records where clear = false with an index. The question just has a feel of "wrongness" in the solution to it. Just offering a different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit off topic:

In case when attachment is stored on S3 - you can just override the `has_attached_file` method and pass only attachment name without any options. Paperclip will think in this case that file is stored in filesystem and will just delete nothing. Also no exception is raised.

I know that this solution may be a little bit hacky/ugly but is simple and works.

Answer (score 1):

For me overriding the `Paperclip::Attachment#clear` method did not do the trick. I had to override `Paperclip::Attachment#queue_all_for_delete`.

As Alex Falke said, Paperclip has the `:preserve_files` option, so obviously if you wanted to preserve all attachments you would use it instead of overriding.

If you have a special case, overriding `#queue_all_for_delete` is the way to go, but you'll have to do it selectively. Monkey patching is global, so it is not the best approach. I tried to use refinements to limit the monkey patching scope, but the lexical scoping didn't play nicely with my use case.

So I ended up with this module, which injects itself to the method lookup path and selectively defines or undefines a no-op override for `#queue_all_for_delete`:

```
module PaperclipKeepAttachment
  def self.with_patch
    patch
    add_override
    yield
  ensure
    remove_override
  end

  def self.patch
    me = self
    Paperclip::Attachment.class_eval{ prepend me } unless Paperclip::Attachment.ancestors.include?(me)
  end

  def self.add_override
    define_method(:queue_all_for_delete) do
      # no-op
    end
  end

  def self.remove_override
    remove_method(:queue_all_for_delete)
  end
end
```

With it you can do something like:

```
PaperclipKeepAttachment.with_patch do 
  # The record will be destroyed but the attachment kept intact
  first_record.destroy
end

# The record will be destroyed and the attachment removed
second_record.destroy
```